# regex extract substring

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I have some SQL code that I am trying to parse and extract some text.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW the_view_name as
```

I want the text between `REPLACE VIEW` and the `AS` which does not include leading or trailing spaces.

At the moment I'm getting the whole lot with `/REPLACE\s*VIEW(.*?)\s*AS/gi`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
 echo 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW the_view_name as' |
     perl -lne '/replace\s+view\s+(.*?)\s+as\b/i && print "[$1]"'
[the_view_name]
```

You can use this regex too in your case :

```
/replace\s+view\s+(\S+)\s+as\b/i
```

See [`perldoc perlrebackslash`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html)

```
\S : Character class for non whitespace
```

Comment: $sqlline =~ /replace\s+view\s+(.*?)\s+as\b/i;
 $viewname = $1;
 print "viewname : $viewname\n";

Answer (score 0):

You're currently missing a space after VIEW, and if you want everything except spaces then your capture group should be `([^\s]*)`, which will collect everything up until a space.

Comment: Thanks;REPLACE\s*VIEW\s*([^\s]*) gives me REPLACE VIEW the_view_name I'm still after only 'the_view_name'